Looking for a rank distance with higher weights for initial items
Assume that the results of a race is as follows: ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], so "a" is the winner. Before the race, person X predicted the results as ["b", "a", "c", "d", "e"] and person Y prediction the results as ["a", "b", "c", "e", "d"]
Currently, I am using (kendall_tau_statistics+1)/2 as the prediction accuracy. However, I am trying to find a better metric since mine does not take into account that predicting 1st (winner) is more important than predicting 5th.
Is there a well-established way of measuring this?
